# Spring autowire before constructor

Tags: spring, autowired

Hi, I have a class that I want to test. This class has an autowired DAO object this object is been used in a `@PostConstruct` method, but I want to use the mock and not the real object is there a way. Here is an example:

```
@Autowired
PersonDao personDao;
//Constructor 
public Person()
{
    //Do stuff
}

@PostConstruct
void init()
{
    //I need it to be a mock
    personDao.add(new Person());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use mocked `PersonDao` you have several choices:

- defines `PersonDao` mock as a Spring bean with `primary="true"` attribute so that it will have precedence over normal bean
- move autowiring to constructor and create `Person` manually by providing a mock:

  ```
  PersonDao personDao;

  @Autowired
  public Person(PersonDao personDao)
  {
      this.personDao = personDao;
  }
  ```

  then:

  ```
  new Person(personDaoMock)
  ```

  and don't rely on Spring.
- you can modify private field using [`ReflectionTestUtils`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html):

  ```
  ReflectionTestUtils.setField(person, "personDao", mock);
  ```